# How to show images taken 10 minutes ago in android gallery?

Tags: java, android, android-gallery

I want the ability to allow the user to choose an image from the gallery, 
but only images were taken, for example, 10 minutes ago (maybe using Time Created Metadata?).

There are examples of how to open gallery and choose an image:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

However, I only need images which were taken 10 minutes ago.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong but I don't think you can achieve this directly by using the `Intent.ACTION_PICK` into the `Gallery`. I think, there is a possible way with `MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN` and a `Cursor` as you can see [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9005709/2668136). However, I did not find the right way to do it.

Then, you can do a workaround: create your own `Gallery` into your app. Select all the pictures from the `Camera` folder, filter them, and display only which are taken *x* min ago into your own `Gallery` - a simple `GridView`. I think this might be easy to do:

- Init the `var`s:

  ```
  // FileArray
  private File[] aFile;
  // ArrayList
  private ArrayList<String> aImagePath = new ArrayList<String>();
  ```
- Get the `DCIM Camera` folder:

  ```
  File fPath = new File(Environment
                   .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/DCIM/Camera");
  ```
- Create a `FileArray` and list the files in this folder:

  ```
  // use a FilenameFilter to have only the pictures in JPG
  aFile = fPath.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
      public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
          return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg");
      }
  });
  ```
- For each file, get the last modified date and populate an `ArrayList<String>`:

  ```
  for(int i=0; i < aFile.length; i++) {
      long lastDate = aFile[i].lastModified();  // get last modified date
      long nowTime = nDate.getTime();  // get the current time to compare
      if(nowTime - lastDate < 600*1000) {  // if less than 10 min
          String pathFile = aFile[i].getPath(); 
          aImagePath.add(pathFile);  // populate the Array
      }
  }
  ```
- Finally, reverse the `Array` to have the most recent pictures at the first place and display them:

  ```
  if(aImagePath.size() != 0) {
      Collections.reverse(aImagePath);  // reverse the Array

      // Call an AsyncTask to create and retrieve each Bitmap
      // then, in onPostExecute(), populate the Adapter of the GridView
  } else {
      // No pictures taken 10 min ago!
  }
  ```

Actually, in the `AsyncTask`, you will have to deal with the `Bitmap` options to save memory... I tested this in a `GridView` into a `Fragment` and it worked well. You can find the references I used above:

- [Using File.listFiles with FileNameExtensionFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5751357/2668136)
- [How to get a file's creation date?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2390177/2668136)
- [Get File Creation Time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9169930/2668136)
- [How to display selected image gallery in ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18628048/2668136)

Maybe someone has a better solution, but this above does the trick and displays only the images taken 10 min ago with the `Camera`'s device. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Not every phone stores the Camera's photos in `DCIM/Camera` folder some dose in `DCIM/100MEDIA` some `DCIM/100ANDRO` ...

Comment: i will start my filtered photo gallery app from your answer ;)

Comment: Hope this will help you, @NicolasManzini. But, as Pedram says, be careful to the folder selection. It's not the same for all device.